# How to use offline routing Dijkstra in javascript?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, routing, offline

I am using a Openlayers 3 to create a Hybrid mapping app and among the constraints it must be for offline use, I have a road network in a geojson file and I need to get the shortest path from the location of the user to a destination following the roads network.

I tried pgrouting before and it worked well but now I need to do so without relying on any server.

Is there any way I can make it with javascript and Openlayers 3? Is there any library that can do offline routing ?

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNEnZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNEnZ.png)hicham-zouarhi i have also same problem.Did you solve this issue....................

Comment: @FarjanaKhan I solved it by coding it in Javascript rather than using Graphhopper, see my answer below, there is a link to the github repo with a little description of the code

Comment: Hicham Zouarhi ************ https://github.com/HichamZouarhi/offline-routing-OL3 its not working offline

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/122608)

Comment: @FarjanaKhan it does work offline if you download the js files required, and there is also an html file with a demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this problem I made a little tool to get the shortest path using dijkstra algorithm in OL3 [here](https://github.com/HichamZouarhi/offline-routing-OL3)

first you create the network based on the feature collection you have :

```
var network = createNetwork(yourFeatureCollection);
```

then you get the shortest path as a geometry of the path :

```
var shortestPath = getShortestPath(network, coordsSource, coordsDestination);
```

Answer (score 2):

GraphHopper is able to run offline in the Browser with the help of [TeaVM](http://teavm.org/)

- See [here](http://www.teavm.org/live-examples/graphhopper/index.html) for the examples.
- See [here](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2014/05/04/graphhopper-in-the-browser-teavm-makes-offline-routing-via-openstreetmap-possible-in-javascript/) the blog post about it
- See [here](https://github.com/konsoletyper/teavm-graphhopper) is the source repository

Note: I'm the author of GraphHopper ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and thanks for this great tool, I signed up yesterday and began looking around its features.

Comment: 'Sign up' you mean probably our commercial took the GraphHopper Directions API ... keep in mind that this works only online! See the link to the source repo for the offline&open source solution :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I am trying to set it up but I can't figure out how. I am new to git so I downloaded the graphhopper-master.zip first but I can't find any js file so I went to the Get started section in your blog, build teavm part was fine ( I guess ) and I cloned the modified Graphhopper, the next command 
    mvn clean package -DskipTests=true
got me this error

Comment: [ERROR] Plugin org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:0.2-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.teavm:teavm-maven-plugin:pom:0.2-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

I have no clue if this is how it must be done, can you help please ?

Comment: Please raise the issues related to this project on the github issue page